# Solve the system of equations $2x^{5}- 2x^{3}y- x^{2}y+ 10x^{3}+ y^{2}- 5y= 0$ ...

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, radicals

Solve the system of equations
$$\begin{matrix}
2x^{5}- 2x^{3}y- xy^{2}+ 10x^{3}+ y^{2}- 5y= 0\\ 
\left ( x+ 1 \right )\sqrt{y+ 5}= y- 3x^{2}+ x- 2
\end{matrix}$$
**My try**
$$\left ( 1- x \right )y^{2}- \left ( 5+ 2x^{3} \right )y+ 2x^{5}+ 10x^{3}=0\\
\Delta _{y}= \left ( 5+ 2x^{3} \right )^{2}- 4\left ( 1- x \right )\left ( 2x^{5}+ 10x^{3} \right )\geq  0$$
Then I used Wolfram Alpha, the inequality plot is
                      [image]

I can' t continue. I need the help. Thanks!

Comment: What is $\Delta_y?$

Comment: @IgorRivin The discriminant of the quadratic equation w.r.t $y$

Answer (score 0):

Solving your second equation for $y$ we get:
$$y_1=3\,{x}^{2}+ \left( x/2+1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {13\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+29} \right) x-
x/2+5/2+1/2\,\sqrt {13\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+29}
$$
or
$$y_2=3\,{x}^{2}+ \left( x/2+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {13\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+29} \right) x-
x/2+5/2-1/2\,\sqrt {13\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+29}
$$
plugging this into the first equation we get the following polynomial (after squaring again)
$$157\,{x}^{10}-466\,{x}^{9}+281\,{x}^{8}-663\,{x}^{7}+345\,{x}^{6}-405
\,{x}^{5}-242\,{x}^{4}+121\,{x}^{3}-190\,{x}^{2}+x+1
=0$$
which can only be solved by a numerical way.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics of the system is

[image: two curves intersections]

Therefore the solution are

$x=-1,  y=6$ and $x=2-\frac{\sqrt{39}}{3},  y=\frac{40}{3}-\frac{4*\sqrt{39}}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-After some handling we have two quadratic equations in $y$:
$$y^2-(5-7x^2)y+(9x^4-6x^3+8x^2-14x-1)=0\\(1-x)y^2-(5+2x^3)y+(2x^5+10x^3)=0$$
A way to find out the real roots of this system is a bit of work after plotting the corresponding curves. We have the six following approximate real roots:
$$(x,y)=(-0.0686,0),(0.9604,1.5639),(-0.2063,4.148),(0.0592,5.314),(-4.962,-60288),(2.6401,-33.506)$$ The other non-real roots are four of difficult calculation.