# $\left ( x+ 1 \right )\sqrt{y- 5}= y- 3x^{2}+ x- 2\Leftrightarrow y= 6x^{2}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

I want to prove

$$\left ( x+ 1 \right )\sqrt{y- 5}= y- 3x^{2}+ x- 2\Leftrightarrow  y= 6x^{2}$$

Who can help me? If this problem be solved, I can solve the system was posted here:

[Solve the system of equations $2x^{5}- 2x^{3}y- xy^{2}+ 10x^{3}+ y^{2}- 5y= 0$ ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711250/solve-the-system-of-equations-2x5-2x3y-xy2-10x3-y2-5y-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If you change the sign to $\sqrt{y-5}$, the system has no solution

Comment: The Author post is wrong. I have corrected it. I can show you see: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+2x%5E5-+2x%5E3y-+x%5E2y%2B+10x%5E3%2B+y%5E2-+5y%3D+0+with+%5Cleft+(+x%2B+1+%5Cright+)%5Csqrt%7By-+5%7D%3D+y-+3x%5E%7B2%7D%2B+x-+2

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. We can very easily see this by actually setting $y=6x^2$, since then we get

$$\left ( x+ 1 \right )\sqrt{6x^2+ 5}= 6x^2- 3x^{2}+ x- 2$$

since now on the right we have a polynomial and on the left we don't. We can even prove this further by setting $x=0$, to see that $\sqrt5 = -2$.

---

Even after the edit, the same argument applies. We can still set $x=2$ to see $3\sqrt{19}=12$.

Comment: My idea is transforming the first equation into the product of $y-6x^2$

Comment: Why do you think there is a factor of $y-6x^2$ in the equation?

Comment: because the system has some roots $(1,6), (-1,6), (3,54)$ and then we have $2x^{5}- 2x^{3}y- x^{2}y+ 10x^{3}+y^{2}- 5y= -10(x-3)(x-1)x^{2}(x+1)$. The author's problem is wrong. I have correct it!